# How to access EJB3 remotely?

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

> I am using JBOSS AS-7 as SERVER-A and tomcat as SERVER-B.

I have developed an EJB and deployed it on SERVER-A in a JAR, and I want to call this EJB from Server-B. The problem is how, can I access the EJB from SERVER-B?

The EJB code is given below :

```
package demo.ejb;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface RemoteBeanInterface {

   public void say(String saying);
}


package demo.ejb.session.stateless;

import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import demo.ejb.RemoteBeanInterface;

@Stateless(name = "StatelessBeanDemo")
public class StatelessBeanDemo implements RemoteBeanInterface {

   @Override
   public void say(String saying) {
      System.out.println("[Say] : " + saying + "");
   }
}
```

Can, anyone help me how can I access/call EJB from SERVER-B?

Comment: Does this help https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+server+instance

Comment: @mprabhat your example is only between 2 JBoss servers, the question is to look up from a tomcat server, this link is more appropriated: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI

Answer (score 0):

In this example you can find all you need to lookup a remote EJB in JBoss.
It includes also the maven dependencies you will need, take a look in the client project.

https://github.com/jbossas/quickstart/tree/master/ejb-remote/

Comment: I have use client side of this soruce to call EJB3. But id doesn't work.